# PHP Laravel artisan vendor:publish command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

How can I make PHP's artisan `vendor:publish` command to merge the new file with the existing file instead overwriting in Laravel? Or after a `make:console` merge, how can I use the `vendor:publish` command in it?

I ask because PHP's artisan `vendor:publish --force` overwrites packages view for a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP artisan does't publish files. If it is already published then only look for new files (don't use --force). Also, you can use

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Vendor\Providers\PackageServiceProvider"
```

to specify package